# Connecting two or more arduino boards to a single Pi board

Tags: serial, arduino

I was wondering what are the pin configurations/connections and scripting to connect more than 1 arduino to a single raspberry Pi board via serial connection.

Comment: Give the details of what you have tried during your research.